Write CodeQL Script to Check Pointers Before Pointer Field Access
Given the example code below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int name;
} type4;

typedef struct {
    int name;
    type4 *p4;
} type3;

typedef struct {
    int name;
    type3 *p3;
} type2;

typedef struct {
    int name;
    type2* p2;
} type1;

int main(void){

    type1 *p1       = malloc(sizeof(type1));
    p1->p2          = malloc(sizeof(type2));
    p1->p2->p3      = malloc(sizeof(type3));
    p1->p2->p3->p4  = malloc(sizeof(type4));

    printf("p4: %d\n", p1->p2->p3->p4->name);

    free(p1->p2->p3->p4);
    free(p1->p2->p3);
    free(p1->p2);
    free(p1);

    return 0;
}

I want to write a CodeQL script to make sure:

before p1->p2, the nullness of p1 is checked, i.e., if(p1) { p1->p2; }
before p1->p2->p3, the nullness of p1->p2 is checked, i.e., if(p1->p2){ p1->p2->p3; }
...

Before TaintTracking and everything, I need to first find a way to express p1, p1->p2, p1->p2->p3, ..., but I just couldn't.
Here is my attempt:
/**
* @id pointers-test
* @kind problem
* @problem.severity warning
*/

import cpp

class StartOfPointerFieldAccess extends Variable {
    StartOfPointerFieldAccess(){
    exists(PointerFieldAccess pfa, LocalVariable v|
        v.getType() instanceof PointerType
        and pfa.getQualifier+().(VariableAccess).getTarget() = v
        and this = v
        )
    }
}

from PointerFieldAccess pfa, StartOfPointerFieldAccess pv
where pfa.getQualifier+().(VariableAccess).getTarget() = pv
select pfa, "Interesting Pointer Field Access."

The issue is that my script only returns individual fields (p1, p2, p3, ...), instead of the entire chain (such as p1->p2->p3), while concat doesn't support complex types (such as PointerFieldAccess), so I couldn't combine my results either.
P.S. the C source and the QL script are tested and usable.

C and C++ are different languages. This looks like C, so please remove the C++ tag.

@wohlstad this is also applicable in C++, it's all about pointer field access. But I will listen to your suggestion.

Answering my own question. This is solved by CodeQL's team, the missing element was IR (Intermediate Representation) component of CodeQL.
/**
 * @kind problem
 */

import semmle.code.cpp.controlflow.Guards
import semmle.code.cpp.ir.ValueNumbering

/** Holds if `instr` is guarded to be non-null */
predicate isNullGuarded(Instruction instr) {
  any(IRGuardCondition gc).ensuresEq(valueNumber(instr).getAUse(), 0, instr.getBlock(), false)
}

from LoadInstruction load, Instruction qualifier, PointerFieldAccess pfa
where
  // The load is from a load of a pointer field access
  load.getUnconvertedResultExpression() = pfa and
  qualifier.getUnconvertedResultExpression() = pfa.getQualifier() and
  not isNullGuarded(qualifier)
select pfa, "This dereference is not guarded."

I am explaining the logic here, in case anyone needs to turn it into a TaintTracking script:

LoadInstruction: such as assigning an address into a variable, or loading a chunk of memory, such as if(a_pointer){...}
.getQualifier(): according to CodeQL, for ptr->x, this gives ptr.

So the script is basically finding (explaining from/where/select line by line):

a load instruction, where the unconverted expression is a Pointer Field Access (such as ptr->x)
the unconverted qualifier of the Pointer Field Access (the ptr in ptr->x), it is specifically an unconverted qualifier, because you want to examine the entirety of ptr1->ptr2->x and not just ptr2->x
the unconverted qualifier is not null guarded


I saw you really needed this to work, nice one, great work
